# Groovy Script Illegal use of nonvirtual function call

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

When i run groovy script in eclipse & jenkins I am getting below error :

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class:
groovy/runtime/metaclass/java/lang/StringMetaClass, method:
super$2$invokeMissingMethod signature:
(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;)
Illegal use of nonvirtual function call
```

But when I ran from groovy console I am able to execute code without this error . I have tried with jre 6,7,8 nothing helps.. Can anyone help me on this issue.

Comment: What version of groovy? And what exact versions of Java?

Comment: groovy 2.4.6 and jdk1.7.0_72

Comment: I am getting this same error with groovy 2.4.15, jdk1.8.0_161 and jenkins LTS 107.1.  How is it resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins 1.x ships with Groovy 1.8.9, so your script needs to be compatible with Groovy 1.8 when running in Jenkins script console or CLI commands.

The upcoming Jenkins 2.0 release will ship with Groovy 2.4.6.

See [JENKINS-21249](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21249) for details.